# VIX_E_HOST_NETWORK_CONN_REFUSED verify if i'm connected to ESX(i) host directly

Tags: c#, vmware

I have such network configuration:
- myApp: network1
- vCentre: network1, network2
- EsxHost: network2

So, myApp cannot see EsxHost directly. I get VIX_E_HOST_NETWORK_CONN_REFUSED error. 
I've found, that such situation is incorrect: http://pangkwongluk.blogspot.com/2011/10/avvi-backup-fails-with-error-unable-to.html

But I have to verify if host is "seen" by me and give appropriate notification in C# app.

Comment: I use vixDiskLib. I connect correctly to vCentre using VixDiskLib_ConnectEx, but it verifies that vCentre is OK. Error occurs when I use VixDiskLib_Open. It's parameters include path to my vmdk file (datastore, name), that is related with ESXHost. I tried to use VixDiskLib_ConnectEx with my ESXHost, but don't know correct parameters to put.